# How do I mix php inside php strings?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to mix `<?php echo do_shortcode('[...]')` with a field from Advanced Custom Fields within Wordpress.

So basically what I'm trying to do is give the user a text field in the page edit screen where she can paste in the ID of a youtube vide. This field will then update my `do_shortcode` to display the correct video.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong considering I've done this several times before and been succesful. I do have a feeling I'm not escaping the string correctly?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[video_lightbox_youtube video_id="' . the_field("youtube_video") . '" width="640" height="480" anchor="Play Video"]'); ?>
```

Anyone able to lead me in the right direction? :)

*EDIT*

The code above returns `q_cHD1lcEOo` with multiple spaces in front of it as well as this: `"Error! You must specify a value for the Video ID, Width, Height parameters to use this shortcode!"` That's why I was thinking I'm not escaping it correctly as these are all specified.

I'll add that if I remove `the_field("...")` and replace it with just an ID it displays perfectly.

*SECOND EDIT*

Since I was not supposed to echo it, I was using the wrong function to get the field. Instead of using `the_field()` which prints the value, I was supposed to use `get_field()` to simply return it to the string.

Comment: What is going wrong? Are there any errors? Can you debug your code, check what the_field returns (does it return anything, or echo's it? That could cause your problem!)

Comment: This is confusing. Normally, I'd suggest concatenation to perform other manipulations inside strings, but the examples would not benefit from concatenation

Comment: @TJHeuvel I was able to fix it. You nudged me in the right direction. Instead of using the_field I was obviously supposed to use get_field instead :) thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it looks like you should be using `get_field` instead of `the_field`.  `the_field` will print without being prompted, whereas `get_field` will return its value, which is what you want.

I see you've also mentioned whitespace at the start, you should consider wrapping the function in `trim`.

See below:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[video_lightbox_youtube video_id="' . trim(get_field("youtube_video")) . '" width="640" height="480" anchor="Play Video"]'); ?>
```

Comment: The whitespace problem fixed itself once I changed to `get_field` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I'm also 20 hours without sleep.

Anyways, as far as mixing PHP within a PHP string, there's numerous ways to do it..

You can use concatenation or { } within the string itself.

For example, say we want to echo out the property of an object within a string.

We could do the following

```
echo "This is my property " . $object->property;
```

Or, we can do this

```
echo "This is my property {$object->property}";
```

You can even do cool things like access associative arrays within strings like so

```
echo "This is my property {$object->property['cool']}";
```

Hopefully this leads you in the ride direction.

Comment: Hey Braydon. Thanks for this, I didn't know you could use `{}` to mix php in a string, that looks so much cleaner! I did manage to find out what was wrong, and it didn't really have anything to do with mixing php since it turned out I used the wrong function for the ACF-plugin :)